SPFX Form Customizer Edit and Display form gives Error
I am trying to use Spfx form customizer (react) in my portal. I created the form customizer solution and only added hello world in side the default empty div. After deploying the solution to my farm I used the pnpjs to add the customizer to a list as new, edit and display form. When I click new item my custom form opens without an error but when I tried to open edit or display forms it gives an error (Sorry something went wrong) and in the console I am getting the error below

I tried this with multiple solutions but result is always the same. I added console.log for form load to see when is this problem occurs but none of the log texts shown in the console for display and edit form.
Am I missing some configuration or doing something wrong?
Edit: I add the detailed error screenshots below. first one is detailed error message second one is the clickable function in the error.



Have you tried to click that link? I mean, the blue text looks clickable. Also you can click the black triangle on the left side, to see what is causing the error (call stack)

Hi, I add the detailed screenshots to my original post, basically they are not very helpful. Also as long as the page stays open it keeps triggering that function and keeps giving the same error in the console.

You could use the stack trace to find what exactly it is trying to parse as JSON, i.e. from where does it come. Maybe some web part settings.

Unfortunately stack trace is only shows the function _onmessage, nothing else :(
